# JS debugging processes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, debugging, firebug

Scenario:  I have a plugin that is in use on a third-party's site, and I have to debug some conflicting JS and CSS.  I don't have access to anything on their site other than the public page that is having the problem.  The JS is all minified and there's a lot of it.

How do I have Firebug (or something else) beautify the JS it shows me while I try to debug?

Is there a way to tell the debugger to step through every line of JS that executes after a certain element is clicked, or otherwise expose in a step-by-step fashion portions of what is being executed?

Is there a current nuts-and-bolts overview on how to do this sort of thing somewhere on the web, or here on SO?

Answer (score 3):

Chrome Developer Tools can unfold the minified code to make it more readable. You can also set up breakpoints for changes in DOM and see what events are listened to.

You should also check out source maps (see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/), you might find them perhaps useful for mapping from minified to non-minified source code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Chrome developer tools. or this sites

1. [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)